# why when i put v-dialog in v-for i can not click multi time, it will take firefox slow

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

i wondering why when i use v-dialog in v-for and i try to reopen and re close dialog in many times
it will take firefox down,firefox hang and i have to close firefox

this is the code

```
<template>
    <v-row>
        <v-col v-for="n in 6" :key=n>
            <v-card
            >
                <v-card-actions>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <v-dialog
                        v-model="dialog"
                        width="500"
                        >
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                            <v-btn
                            v-bind="attrs"
                            v-on="on"
                            >
                            Click Me
                            </v-btn>
                        </template>

                        <v-card>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-card-actions>
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-btn
                                color="primary"
                                text
                                @click="dialog = false"
                            >
                                I accept
                            </v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                        </v-card>
                        </v-dialog>
                    </div>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

and this is the scrip code, is only return for v dialog

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            dialog: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

that code above is pure v-dialog vuetify, i only put that in card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to move the `v-dialog` out the loop :

```
<template>
    <v-row>
            <v-dialog
                        v-model="dialog"
                        width="500"
                        >
                        <v-card>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-card-actions>
                            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                            <v-btn
                                color="primary"
                                text
                                @click="dialog = false"
                            >
                                I accept
                            </v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                        </v-card>
            </v-dialog>
        <v-col v-for="n in 6" :key=n>
            <v-card
            >
                <v-card-actions>
                    <div class="text-center">
                         <v-btn
                            color="primary"
                            @click.stop="dialog=true"
                            >
                            Click Me
                            </v-btn>
                    </div>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
```